# http://localhost:8529/_api/query/225 - syntax correct?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to abort a long running query (with id 225) with the new API feature for the first time. But I can't get it killing the request. the API request answers with

```
   {"error":true,"code":404,"errorNum":404,"errorMessage":"not found"}
```

although the query still is running.

```
[
  {
    "id": "225",
    "query": [SNIP]
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can only guess as the question does not contain full information on what is actually posted and with which HTTP method.

My guess is that you used HTTP GET when you tried killing the query and not HTTP DELETE. So the URL was probably correct but not the HTTP method. In this case you will also get a 404 error.

There are two ways for terminating a running query:

- using the ArangoShell

  First of all, the query id needs to be determined. This can be achieved as follows:
  `require("org/arangodb/aql/queries").current();`

  Using the returned `id` value, the command to kill the query is:
  `require("org/arangodb/aql/queries").kill(id);`
- using HTTP

  When the query is known, it can be used in an HTTP DELETE request:
  `curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8529/_api/query/id`

  Again, `id` needs to be query's real id.

Comment: Your guess was right, I did not use HTTP DELETE, as (untypically?) the API UI can not be used, it misses the input form for the query id. So I was too naive and simply built a GET url in the browser by mistake. Thanks. Maybe somebody wants to give the API UI the missing input form in some "on-the-fly-situation" ... until then, the ArangoShell mechanism does work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have fixed the docs so they will include the missing query-id parameter from the next release on.